# `*this` is not allowed here, ask for a solution

Tags: c++

I want to use a member function to call the current object itself, but I got an error complaning:

```
error: reference to type 'const block' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'block *'
            if (otherBlks[mm].theNeighbourPolyline(this) == 1)
                                                   ^~~~
~/blockI.hpp:358:59: note: passing argument to parameter 'blockX' here
inline const int block::theNeighbourPolyline(const block& blockX) const
```

The error happens as I am trying to add a new member function `void block::bdsmooth(const vector<block>& otherBlks)`. In this member function, the `theNeighbourPolyline(otherBlks[mm])` works fine, but `otherBlks[mm].theNeighbourPolyline(this)` seems to be not allowed.

What should I do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a pointer value, but your function is looking for a reference parameter. Try:

```
if (otherBlks[mm].theNeighbourPolyline(*this) == 1)
```

Comment: OOPS, I sit before the computer too long.

Comment: We all have those days.  :-)